# Make Link Colors Brighter and/or add Dotted Underline

Tags: feature-request

**I think links are a pretty important aspect of many answers.** However, while reading an answer (and I was rereading it for about 30 minutes), I never noticed that there was actually a link in the answer as the color is very similar to the surrounding text's color. Ofcourse, this is completely subjective, other's might be seeing it just fine, but I think overall, visually, links can be improved. (I'm not color blind or anything).

Here's a picture. (Also I must admit, after I saw it I can't unsee the dark blue, but still on my screen it's pretty hard to see). 
[image]

Comment: Any chance of some movement on this? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342089/at-sign-after-shebang where several readers didn't notice that there's a link in the first line of the question.

Answer (score 7):

### Suggestion: Make links brighter, add dotted underline

My suggestion is to make all links a brighter blue or a different brighter color and/or add dotted underline to all links to make it very clear there's a link. Meta.Stackoverflow uses this:

[image]

Comment: Agreed. Underlining, in particular, is an important accessibility feature for the colour blind and visually impaired.